# How to allow users to only open PDF file but not save them

Tags: security, pdf

How can I allow users to open PDF file but not save them. All User's PCs are using Windows and do not have admin permission. 
I remember when i downloaded Game Magazine via online they let me download certificate first so i could open the PDF Game Magazine. Can i do something like that? Or is there better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is "whatever you give to the user is not yours anymore". So there's no reliable way to prevent saving. Adobe tried to implement some kind of DRM solution with its Reader, but it works only for Reader and any application or library that can open the PDF would be able to save the data (should the developers decide to ignore the flags in the PDF).

Comment: What do you mean by (should the developers decide to ignore the flags in the PDF). I got the idea of having an android app to OPEN a pdf file, but ONLY my app.

Comment: @user2427819 The actions the application may take in regards to the document are specified in document properties. The application then must obey those flags. But nothing prevents this application from ignoring the flags and doing what's forbidden.

Comment: I finally had the idea of encrypting the file using DES, and decrypting it on the device to open it